# Resteasy and CorsFilter implementation

Tags: java, rest, cors, jboss7.x, resteasy

I'm trying implement the CorsFilter from Resteasy (3.0.16). My currently environment is: **java 7** and **jboss 7.1**. I've tried several ways, but no one works.

Actually CorsFeature.java (@Provider) it's never instantiate, and i can't get the correct headers. I also tried override methods in Application class (with web.xml and so on) but CorsFeature never intercepts anything.

Here is my code, if anyone can help me:

*pom.xml*

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        // I also tried put <scope>provided...
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

*Application.java*

```
@ApplicationPath("") 
public class BaseApplication extends Application 
{}
```

*CorsFeature.java*

```
@Provider
public class CorsFeature implements Feature {
public CorsFeature() {
System.out.println("never init..");
}
@Override
public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter();
corsFilter.getAllowedOrigins().add("*");
context.register(corsFilter);
return true;
}
}
```

*Service*

```
@POST
    @Path("/new")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response sendEmail() {
        String value = "new";
        return Response.status(200).entity(value).build();
    }
```

Headers response:

```
Content-Length → 11
Content-Type → */*
Date → Sat, 09 Apr 2016 00:07:03 GMT
Server → Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

*Regards*

Comment: Try it with Wildfly. I think Jboss 7 uses Java EE 6, which is JAX-RS 1.x. `Feature` is not introduced until JAX-RS 2.0...